# sticky top not working throughout the page. Only working for header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Below is my code for my portfolio site. The sticky top is not working for the full page. Please help.
It is only working for the header but not working for other divs. I don't know where I am doing wrong. I have also tried making it fixed, but it is not helping.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background: url("image5.jpg") no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  color: black !important;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  color: black !important;
}

.nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: aliceblue !important;
}

.main h1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #ff0000;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.main p {
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.education {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.education .eduarea {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
}

.education h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mx-auto">
    <header>

      <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#1">Education</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Training</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Experience</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1> I am Subhadeepta Sahoo</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br/> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,<br/> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
              specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="education" id="2">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Education</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid eduarea">
        <h4> Heading 1</h4>
        <p> M.Tech</p>
        <h4> Heading 2</h4>
        <p>B.Tech</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="file.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I haven't used any javascript here. If it is necessary to use, then please let me know how to use it.

Comment: Do you want the navbar to be fixed?

Comment: I want my navbar to be sticky.

Comment: Try .navbar{position:fixed;}

Comment: I have tried but after that there shows white blank space between the navbar and the image

Comment: `. sticky-top` in your code has no `position: sticky`, If you add `position: sticky` to `nav`, the DOM will be limited to the bottom of  `.header`.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/